# Why does this javascript not work in chrome while it does in ie?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, google-chrome

It is a very simple calculation script and I don't know why it does not work in chrome. I'm so confused. A search here and the net for days did not work. I'm stuck.

```
Isyerindeki Çalisan Sayisi: <input type="text" name="n"> <button onclick="myFunction()">Hesapla</button>
<p id="sonucat"></p>
<p id="sonuct"></p>
<p id="sonucct"></p>
<script>
    function myFunction() {
        var a = Number(n.value);
        var at = 4
        var t = 6
        var ct = 8
        var sat = a * at;
        var st = a * t;
        var sct = a * ct;

        if (a <= 9) { 
            var sat = 25; 
            document.getElementById("sonucat").innerHTML = "AZ TEHLIKELI isyerlerinde yilda en az " + sat + ",";
            document.getElementById("sonuct").innerHTML = "TEHLIKELI isyerlerinde ayda en az " + st + ",";
            document.getElementById("sonucct").innerHTML = "ÇOK TEHLIKELI isyerlerinde ayda en az " + sct + " dakika isyeri hekimi çalistirmakla yükümlüsünüz.";
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById("sonucat").innerHTML = "AZ TEHLIKELI isyerlerinde ayda en az " + sat + ",";
            document.getElementById("sonuct").innerHTML = "TEHLIKELI isyerlerinde ayda en az " + st + ",";
            document.getElementById("sonucct").innerHTML = "ÇOK TEHLIKELI isyerlerinde ayda en az " + sct + " dakika isyeri hekimi çalistirmakla yükümlüsünüz.";
        }
    }
</script>
```

Comment: I'm getting a `ReferenceError: n is not defined` when I try this in Firefox, but I'm on a mac so I can't see how this would work in IE.  Here is a demo: http://jsfiddle.net/8pp0c8hn/ is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: If the function is declared after the HTML like you posted then `myFunction` will be undefined in the HTML

Comment: Thank you for your interest and quick answer. But I could not get your demo run in chrome. SjoerdDeWit's solution works. :)

Answer (score 2):

It's because IE create variable based on the element `name` when Chrome does not so your `n.value` has no meaning for it.

So you need to select it, for example add an `id="a"` then use `document.getElementById("a")`

Your `onclick` is also wrong though, `myFunction()` would call the function when the DOM is read not on click, should be `myFunction`. Also best to stay away from attribute when it comes to binding.

```
function myFunction() {
    var a = Number(document.getElementyId("myId").value);
    var at = 4
    var t = 6
    var ct = 8
    var sat = a * at;
    var st = a * t;
    var sct = a * ct;

    if (a <= 9) { 
    var sat = 25; 
        document.getElementById("sonucat").innerHTML = "AZ TEHLİKELİ işyerlerinde yılda en az " + sat + ",";
        document.getElementById("sonuct").innerHTML = "TEHLİKELİ işyerlerinde ayda en az " + st + ",";
        document.getElementById("sonucct").innerHTML = "ÇOK TEHLİKELİ işyerlerinde ayda en az " + sct + " dakika işyeri hekimi çalıştırmakla yükümlüsünüz.";
    }
    else {
        document.getElementById("sonucat").innerHTML = "AZ TEHLİKELİ işyerlerinde ayda en az " + sat + ",";
        document.getElementById("sonuct").innerHTML = "TEHLİKELİ işyerlerinde ayda en az " + st + ",";
        document.getElementById("sonucct").innerHTML = "ÇOK TEHLİKELİ işyerlerinde ayda en az " + sct + " dakika işyeri hekimi çalıştırmakla yükümlüsünüz.";
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your interest and reply buddy. :)

Answer (score 1):

your declaring n.value wrong,

change these 2 lines

```
<input type="text" name="n">
var a = Number(n.value);
```

To these 2

```
<input type="text" name="n" id="n">

var n = document.getElementById('n');
var a = Number(n.value);
```

Comment: Done! :) I knew it was simple but somehow I could not find that. I realized that I was very close. I found the door but I could not open it obviously. Thank you very much indeed. :)